# Get List of all available Calendars for storing event - iOS (EKEventkit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventstore

I am using EventKit for storing event in a calendar.

Right now I am using `[event setCalendar:self.defaultCalendar];`

Where,

```
self.defaultCalendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.
```

Now, I like to access all available calendar list. As i want to give select desire calendar to user from averrable list.

After looking Apple's document i come to know that i can set any calendar by using delegate method,

```
- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
```

But how can I get/access available calendars (an array of available calendars so I can show that list to user)?

Answer (score 3):

It's relatively simple:

```
EKEntityType type = EKEntityTypeEvent;
NSArray *calendars = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:type];
```

Note that `EKEntityType` can be `EKEntityTypeEvent` or `EKEntityTypeReminder` depending on what you're looking to edit.

Comment: Excellent. I haven't check in my code but I am pretty sure above two lines definitely work for me. Thanks buddy. :)

Comment: @XeS if you happen to ask the next question: please tick this one as being the correct answer